# Around vs. On the Corner

Tags: word-choice

While giving directions, does it make any difference if we say e.g.

> The nearest restaurant is just around the corner.

Or

> The nearest restaurant is just on the corner.

I've checked for possible duplicates but just found a question concerning *at* and *on the corner* while using dummy subjects *it* and *there*.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Round the corner](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/round-the-corner)*** is an idiomatic expression meaning:

> - very near here:
>     *There's a ​great ​restaurant just round the ​corner.*

also:

***[(just) around the corner](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/just-around-the-corner)***:

> - not ​far away, or going to ​happen ​soon:
>     *There's a ​great ​restaurant just around the corner.
>     I'm ​feeling a little ​depressed at the ​moment, but I'm ​sure good ​times are just around the corner.*

***on/at the corner***  meaning is  literal.

Note also the expression:

[On/at every corner](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-at-every-corner):

> - in many ​places along the ​streets of a ​town or ​city:
>     *After the ​game, ​police were ​stationed on every ​corner.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: ***Round*** 10 o' clock means ***about*** 10 o' clock.

Comment: Aha, then 'around' means almost but not exacly 'on the corner'. Thanks got my answer.

Comment: The idea of "around" is "just passed the corner" suggesting a close location.

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

> The nearest restaurant is just **around** the corner.

it is implied to be directions (you are not there), so envision the movement to the corner and past it. *around* indicates this. If you check the definition of [around](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/around) as a preposition, several will work depending on exact context.

> The nearest restaurant is <del>just</del> **on** the corner.

In this example you have a fixed location (*on the corner* being a specific place), so only *on* is needed. You would not use *just* in this context, as there is no time/action reference. More context maybe...

> I was **just on the corner**, so I don't know why I did not see the restaurant.

It works here because I can move.

Comment: No problem. Possibly you meant *addition* not *edition*, though.

Comment: Now, that you brought it up, both then :) actually I meant the part you said _don't use just_ you crossed it out from my original example.

Comment: Got it. Then, you would write "Thanks for the edit."